# Segfault with pthread and concurrency in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to have a thread, that waits until a task is assigned and then will do it, however I'm running into complications.

```
#include "dispatchQueue.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;
task_t *task;

void test1() {
    sleep(1);
    printf("test1 running\n");
}

void* do_stuff(void *args) {
    printf("in do stuff\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("after do stuff has lock\n");
    task_t *task = (task_t *)args;
    (task->work) (task->params);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("after main gets lock\n");
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, do_stuff, task);
    task = task_create(test1, NULL, "test1");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);   
    printf("after main unlocks \n");

    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}
```

The above code will give a segfault, however if I switch the lines pthread_create and task = task_create(), then it works fine. I'm not familiar with C at all, so I'm wondering why this is?

This is how task is created if that helps, at this point I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the way I'm using pthreads.

```
task_t *task_create(void (*work)(void *), void *param, char* name) {
    task_t *task_ptr = malloc(sizeof(task_t));
    if (task_ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory creating a new task!\n");
        return NULL;
    }   
    task_ptr->work = work;
    task_ptr->params = param;
    strcpy(task_ptr->name, name);
    return task_ptr;
}
```

Comment: Use debug features and find out where it fails.

Comment: @tilz0R It fails at (task->work) (task->params);

Comment: `task` is _not_ set _before_ `pthread_create`, so, in `do_stuff`, `args` will be NULL (and the locally scoped `task` will be NULL as well--hence the segfault). Try doing the `task = task_create(test1, NULL, "test1");` _before_ calling `pthread_create`

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks for your answer! I'm trying implement it, so that I pass a pointer to the task to the do_work and when I do assign a task to the pointer I can call a condition variable that'll let the do_work function do the task. 

It was my understanding that since I'm passing a pointer to do_work that points at a task, if I assigned task later it wouldn't matter. I thought task was globally scoped since I initialized it globally... So when I actually initialized it after I initialized the thread it would be fine.

Comment: @WinstonZhao You as passing the value of `task` to the thread. Perhaps you want to pass it a pointer to the global `task` variable so it can get the contents of that variable?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that's exactly what I was trying to do, keyword being trying... I'm not really sure what's wrong in my understanding why?

Comment: It wasn't totally germane to your question, but I noticed that you have several different scoped variables. In your original code, `main` sets the _global_ scope variable [too late as I mentioned previously], but `do_stuff` has its own function scoped variable, so it never uses the global anyway. Since, in the future, you might create multiple threads [in a loop], it is cleaner to move the global scope variable to function scope in `main`

Comment: Why use a mutex for this?  What's wrong with a condvar or semaphore?  Why do users continually misuse mutex?  Is that the only inter-thread comms they are taught?

Comment: @MartinJames your correct it was definitely better to use a semaphore as I have done now, but making mistakes is part of the process :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, do_stuff, task);
task = task_create(test1, NULL, "test1");
```

You're passing junk to the thread. You haven't set `task` to any particular value here, yet you pass it to the thread as a parameter.

```
void* do_stuff(void *args) {         // *** args is garbage here
    printf("in do stuff\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("after do stuff has lock\n");
    task_t *task = (task_t *)args;   // ** So task is garbage here
    (task->work) (task->params);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Here, you initialize `task` from `args`. But `args` has a garbage value.

If you have some kind of collection that's going to track what tasks a thread is going to work on, you have to pass the thread a parameter that allows it to reliably find that collection. In this particular case, `&task` would work.